# Codeigniter 3 migrations: add the Uncategorized posts category at the first migrations run

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I am working on a basic blog application with **Codeigniter 3.1.8** and **Bootstrap 4**.

I use migration files (`001_create_authors.php` up to `005_create_comments.php`) to automatically create the necessary database tables.

In addition to creating the `categories` table, I need to insert the default "Uncategorized" category in it, as posts **must** belong in a category.

[image]

The migration's current code:

```
class Migration_Create_Categories extends CI_Migration
{

  public function up()
  {
    $this->dbforge->add_field(array(
      'id'=>array(
        'type'=>'INT',
        'constraint' => 11,
        'unsigned' => TRUE,
        'auto_increment' => TRUE
      ),

      'author_id'=>array(
        'type'=>'INT',
        'constraint' => 11,
        'unsigned' => TRUE,
      ),

      'name'=>array(
        'type'=>'VARCHAR',
        'constraint' => 255,
      ),

     'created_at'=>array(
        'type'=>'TIMESTAMP',
      )

    ));
    $this->dbforge->add_key('id', TRUE);
    $this->dbforge->create_table('categories');
  }

  public function down()
  {
    $this->dbforge->drop_table('categories');
  }

}
```

What must I add to he above code in order to insert the default "Uncategorized" category in the categories table, at the *first migrations run*?

Comment: Add the `default` constraint to the column.

Comment: `$this->dbforge->create_table('categories');
//your last code

$data = array(
        array(
                //'id'         => leave this as it will auto created
                'author_id'    => 1,
                'name'         => 'Uncategorized'
                //'created_at' => leave it as this will auto created
        )
);

$this->db->insert_batch('categories', $data);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$this->dbforge->create_table('categories');
//after this line
$data = array(
            //'id'         => leave this as it will auto created
            'author_id'    => 1,
            'name'         => 'Uncategorized'
            //'created_at' => leave it as this will auto created 
);

$this->db->insert('categories', $data);
```